# How to resolve the conflict of the properties which have the same name when using quarkus native package?

Tags: quarkus

When I use `quarkus` to build a native-image with the `<quarkus.package.type>native</quarkus.package.type>` and then execute `mvn clean package -Pnative`. The final bytecode will generate successfully but unfortunately the source files in `/META-INF/resources` which have the same name will conflict. eg, I defined two files, the one named `/META-INF/resouces/A`:

```
aaaaaa
```

and the another one have same name `/META-INF/resouces/A`:

```
bbbbbb
```

I except the result should be: `/META-INF/resouces/A`:

```
aaaaaa
bbbbbb
```

but in fact, it always only contains the partly. Can anyone help me resolve it?

thanks a lot.

One last thing, the `/META-INF/resouces/A` files are defined in different jars, and I can't merge
it manually.

Comment: Hi, why did you expect the final output to contain the content of both files?

Comment: Because I used those files to load all implementations of the specified `interface` by spi and all of the implementations are needed.

Comment: Can you show the code you use?

Comment: I would recommend you to use the standard ServiceLoader. IIRC, we merge the service files.

Comment: @GuillaumeSmet The standard `ServiceLoader` can't meet our needs. In fact, we have extended the standard `ServiceLoader` to match multiple implementations by custom metadata, such as group, tags...

Comment: @geoand We use our custom [SpiLoader](https://github.com/esastack/esa-commons/blob/main/commons/src/main/java/esa/commons/spi/SpiLoader.java) and you can see the usage of it from [GetFeatureExtensionTest](https://github.com/esastack/esa-commons/blob/main/commons/src/test/java/esa/commons/spi/extensionloader/GetFeatureExtensionTest.java). And we just want the `quarkus` to merge the files which have the same name when I used `<quarkus.package.type>native</quarkus.package.type>` to build a native-image.

Comment: There is a way to resolve it, and you can get more detailed information from  https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/22054